# Delete fail or success from ContentProviderResult[]?

Tags: java, android, contacts, android-contentprovider

When using `contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null)` then determining success can be done by looking at the return value of how many rows were affected.

However, [deleting a contact through `ContentProviderOperation` and `applyBatch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) returns `ContentProviderResult[]`

How can you identify whether the delete operation was successful or not *from the `ContentProviderResult` object*?

### Did delete fail with ContentProviderOperation ?

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
      new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withSelection(Data._ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(dataId)})
      .build());

ContentProviderResult[] results = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
if (results != null && results[0] != null) {                            
    // How to extract whether success or failure from results[0] ?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would check the count field of the Result and see if it is equal to 1. If you ran the operation in your question twice, the first Result should give you a count of 1 (indicating one row was deleted), while the second Result should give you a count of 0 (indicating no rows were deleted since you already deleted it).

The truth is the operation isn't failing (hence no exception). The query just has no effect the second time around.

Comment: that works! instead of looking at `results.length > 0` or expecting an exception, i had to check for `results[0].count > 0` (which is actually 3 when successfully deleting one contact by name, presumably due to having Google contact list and others with same entry).

Comment: In my test I run a delete twice. The first time I expect 1 deleted row and the second time I expect 0 because it is already deleted. For some strange reason it returns 1 instead of 0 the second time...
I'm deleting a rawContact row.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation for the applyBatch method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E%29) from the Content Resolver class, won't the applyBatch throw an error if any of the operations failed?

> OperationApplicationException  thrown if an application fails. See apply(ContentProvider, ContentProviderResult[], int) for more information.

Comment: Please see comment to saury, at least in my circumstances / testing I don't get an exception (if the targeted contact is not there in the first place)...

Comment: Oh ok. I was actually afraid this might be the case. Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are deleting one contacting so the result of array returned should be of same length. This will validate the operation success/fail

Comment: Thats the trouble, it doesnt in my testing: (1a) I call the delete method and results.length == 1 (1b) I have a look and the contact is indeed deleted in phone Contact (2) I call the delete method again even though the targeted contact is already deleted, but it still returns results.length == 1. And no exception is thrown...